# SMB share across two subnets

Tags: networking, router, nas, samba

I have two routers:

- router A - 192.168.1.1
- router B - 192.168.2.1

Router A has a NAS connected to it (SMB share), and also has a USB drive configured as a SMB share. There are static routes configured on both routers, so I can access the NAS from router B, also `ping 192.168.1.1` from within network B works as expected. From the network A the USB drive can be accessed as `smb://192.168.1.1`.

//edit: Router B is connected to the Internet, router A's WAN is connected to the LAN port of the router B. If connected to the network B I can access all services on router A (including the router's admin UI), except the USB drive.

That's my setup.

**My problem** is that I can't access the USB drive from the network B. Trying to connect to `smb://192.168.1.1` results in connection failure. Both routers run AsusWRT, I have disabled the Firewall and Network Service Filter on router A.

PS. I am aware of a question with the exact same title, the problem discussed is different, though.

Comment: How are the routers connected to each other? (A diagram would be great, but it would already be clearer if you just included _all_ addresses for each router, not only the "LAN" address.) How are your static routes configured? Can you access other, non-SMB services at 192.168.1.1 (e.g. router's web config screen)?

Comment: (and tbh, don't discount the possibility that the router might have built-in hidden firewall rules to prevent "remote" SMB access which you might not be able to do anything about...)

Comment: @user1686 Hidden firewall could very well be possible. AsusWRT is known to do that sort of thing. MerlinWRT (if available for that model router) might work better. At least it gives you FULL control of the firewall.

Comment: @user1686 I eddited the post and have added some information.

Comment: Hey, @user1686 please post your comment as an answer and I'll gladly accept it. It seems your theory about a hidden firewall is right.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems @user1686 is right, it looks like there is a "hidden firewall". After installing Merlin-WRT all started working as expected, without any configuration changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).